# VirtualBox VERR_ACCESS_DENIED error

Tags: 11.10, virtualbox

I installed Ubuntu 11.10 on VBox. The VBox settings I use have been tried and proven for countless other installs I have done in the past. Those are still up and running.

On my latest install of Ubuntu 11.10 on Vbox, things were working well in the initially - I installed Guest Additions and everything was fine. All of a sudden (I was just moving my mouse), I get an accessed denied error that freezes my entire Ubuntu environment. I close the virtual machine and restart it, but now I keep getting this error message:

[image: error message]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This looks like a file access issue from Windows. Try to check file system integrity.

Comment: This doesn't look like a Ubuntu problem. The error log says that Virtual Box can't access the Ubuntu 11.10.vdi file. So the problem is between VB and Windows. Maybe a corrupt file, failing drive or some permission issue in the windows side.

Comment: Thanks, you guys are right. It'weird though as the vdi was on my local and newly-created. It took two system reboots to get it recognized again in VBox. Hopefully, it won't happen again :\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It remind me something

Are you working on an external drive? 
Seems that you've lost connectivity.

You have to stop virtual box and restart the VM. Make out are able to browse this drive from the host when you see this message.

Hope this helps